# SAS scan function excluding numeric characters and other delimiters

Tags: function, sas, delimiter, csv

I am trying to extract words from the following string:

```
%let rule = %str(limit <= amount and debt > 5);
```

However, I want to extract only words `limit` `amount` and `debt` (names of my variables). How can I achieve this in SAS without extracting also `and` and `5` from the string?

Now I have:

```
%let var1 = %scan(&rule., 1, '= < >')
```

however, this also extracts `and` as the third variable and `5` as the fifth variable which I don't want. Do you know how to include also words `and` (or some other word e.g. `or`) and `5` (generally, all numeric characters) into the list of delimiters?

Comment: What is the rule that rejects `and` and `5` as valid words?  Is it because they are not in the list `limit amount debt`?  Do you really have a list of names in advance? If so why are you scanning the string at all?

Comment: This is inside of macro, for which the user sets `rule =`  as one of the parameters of the macro. I need to be able to filter out column names from that `rule` and those column names will be everything except symbols `> < =` and words `and` `or` or numbers, such as `5`.

Comment: Are numbers or underscores allowed inside variable names? e.g. `myvar_1`?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to provide a list of all the variable names you're looking for and search for each one in turn, e.g. using the `index` function. Do you care if the same variable name comes up more than once in your string?

If the goal here is to provide some sort of input validation for your macro then rather than writing your own parser in macro logic, it might be simpler to try actually applying your `&rule` to a single row from the table you're querying,

E.g.

```
data _null_;
  set mytable(obs = 1);
  where &rule;
run;
```

If any of the required variables for `&rule` are not present, this should generate a fairly clear error message in the log.

Comment: But I don't know the names of variables in advance, the user sets `rule` and I need to filter out variable names from that `rule`. Those variable names are every word except `and`, `or`, number such as `5`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **`TRNWORD`** function to replace/remove specific words like `and or`.
Be sure to include leading and trailing spaces so that you don't mess with variable name you want to keep untouched.

You can use the **`COMPRESS`** function to remove the operators, decimal points and all numbers.

This will work so long as your variable names do not contain numbers. If they do, drop the 'd' modifier from the COMPRESS function and amend the macro to use TRNWORD to remove numbers with leading spaces (e.g. `' 5'`), as variables cannot start with digits.

the following macro will extract a specified word from your text string, report the result to the log, and provide the result in a macro variable :

```
%macro extract_word(txt_string, w_num);
    option nonotes;
    data _null_;
        _rule = "&txt_string.";
        _var1 = tranwrd(_rule, ' and ', ' ');
        _var2 = tranwrd(_var1, ' or ', ' ');
        _var3 = compress(_var2, '^=<>.', 'd');
        _word = scan(_var3, &w_num.);
        call symputx("word&w_num.", _word, 'G');
    run;
    options notes;
    %put NOTE: Word&w_num. = &&word&w_num..;
%mEnd extract_word;
```

Here are the results:

```
     %extract_word(%str(&rule.), 1);
NOTE: Word1 = limit
     %extract_word(%str(&rule.), 2);
NOTE: Word2 = amount
     %extract_word(%str(&rule.), 3);
NOTE: Word3 = debt
```